# Smoothing time series with non-constant variance

Tags: time-series, variance, smoothing, noise

I have a discrete time series $x(t)$ $ t = \{0,\Delta t,2\Delta t\dots\}$ in which every point comes with a confidence value $c(t)$ arising from the measurements. You may think of is as the variance or volatility of the time series that changes over time.

I want to smooth this time series such that points with high confidence get weighted more than points with low confidence.

One more thing is that the dynamical system generating $x(t)$ is non-linear and this non-linearity is very important for downstream analysis so I want to preserve it as much as possible.

Which method do you recommend that can perform this (adaptive) smoothing?

Comment: "I want to smooth this time series such that points with low confidence get weighted more than points with high confidence." Shouldn't high confidence points be weighted more? Also, could you say more specifically what $c(t)$ represents and how it's calculated?

Comment: indeed, corrected.

Comment: Why no use LOWESS? It does what you want, it first smooths the point, and give lower weights for further residuals.

Answer (score 0):

If you can treat the confidence values $c(t)$ like inverse-variances, then perhaps you could use a [simple moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average), but with [inverse-variance weighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-variance_weighting).

You'd have to specify a window size $k$, but to get a smoothed value given $x(t-1), ..., x(t-k)$, your formula is $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^k c(t-i) \cdot x(t-i)}{\sum_{i=1}^k c(t-i)}$.

You may have to jigger your confidence scores somewhat so that you can treat them like inverse-variances. I'm sure someone's investigated the properties of this in the context of time series analysis, but for the life of me I don't know what it would be called.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a Kalman filter, or variant on the same to account for non-linear dynamics (unscented say). Then use your confidence interval to set the standard deviation of the measurement errors in the Kalman update. There are plenty of Kalman filter implementations ([list here if you need it](https://www.microprediction.com/blog/popular-timeseries-packages))